# Golang - offline import/mod init

Tags: go, import

Relatively new to Go and wondering if there's any way to start a new project using a dependency you've already called `go get` or `go mod tidy` for in a previous project, without being connected to the internet?
Is there any way to import a whole package without having to reconnect to the internet to download/tidy further subpackages from the same dependency?

Reason I ask is that I don't normally have internet access where I code, so it becomes quite annoying to faff about to get things off the ground.

So far the only thing that seems to work is copying the old project and clearing it out, but that seems kind of ridiculous, even without having to specifically remove things you don't want to use again from the mod/sum files. Surely I'm missing something?

My $GOPATH points to ~/go
The package(s) I hope to use are in $GOPATH/pkg/mod. Would it be too egregious to place pkg/mod on the $GOPATH?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: "The package(s) I hope to use are in $GOPATH/pkg/mod. Would it be too egregious to place pkg/mod on the $GOPATH?" by your own description, `pkg/mod` is already in `GOPATH`. `GOPATH` doesn't work the way you seem to think it does, it's not exactly like `PATH`. In recent versions of Go it's also not generally recommended to set `GOPATH` at all. But, in general, dependency resolution (in most modern languages) is an online activity.

Comment: go now offers [workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces). IME, these only work under `~/workspace` which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vendoring. Run

```
go mod vendor
```

This will create a "vendor" directory and the go tool will use the dependencies from there.

See https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-vendor fore more information.